# Jenkins CI Results CSV

Tags: jenkins

I am attemtping to integrate Jenkins CI and APtest so that my Jenkins run will automatically update APtest results.

I have the ApTest importresults script below but need a way to generate the appropiate CSV file containing all results data from Jenkins.

Can someone help?

APTest import [results](http://www.aptest.com/atm2/documentation/latest/cli/importResults.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do you need all results data in the history of the job / system dumped every single time? Or are you looking for an incremental CSV after the completion of each build?